# Visual Studio 2013 ultimate install

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation

I am trying to install visual studio 2013 ultimate and i have ensured my c++ redistributable copies have been installed, but the system does not detect when i try to install them and yes i have also installed the azure SDK as well, so im asking is do i need to clear out some folders in my windows folder like package data or is it environment related?
Could you please help? any advise would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Did you review the list of "common issues and workarounds" or examine the "log file" (both of which are linked from the dialog you posted)?

Comment: yes i examined the log file all things are pointing to installation exe failed to start so not very informative. #

Comment: What kind of computer do you have? it seems you are trying to install a 64 bit binary and your computer system is 32bit. Make sure you install the right binary.

Comment: no its 64 bit my computer and the package is also as i wouldnt even get to this stage.

Comment: right ok can anyone point me in the direction of a visual studio 2012 professional or ultimate on boxopus as there only seems to be 32 bit isos available.

Comment: Questions asking us to find or recommend an external site (like a link to something on another site) are off-topic. (Just FYI, you can install a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit OS, just not the other way around. IOW, a 32-bit Visual Studio install on Win 64 is fine, but you can't install 64-bit Visual Studio on Win 32.)

Comment: yes i thought so, i thought i was going mad for a second so i dont understand where the error is coming as my computer is 64 bit, there isnt a 64 bit visual studio to start with only 32 bit.

Comment: i get the feeling it is a registry issue.

Comment: this problem has been solved due to 2013 version of the c++ binary are needed and also having full permissions of the package data folder in the c drive.